# execute javascript at asp file when export to excel

Tags: javascript, excel, asp-classic, export-to-excel

I have an ASP file that export data to Excel, it works fine.

I would like to add a confirmation from the user to update database once the excel file was created.

I'm trying with javascript, but javascript code is not executed. I think this happens because everything is printed at excel file.  Any suggestion?

```
<%Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "inline; filename=demo.xls"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body leftmargin=10 topmargin=0 rightmargin=0 bottommargin=0>
this is a sample page
<script>
if(confirm("Do you want to update the database?"))
    window.location.href="updater.asp";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try enclosing the line following `if` block in parantheses. If that doesn't work try `window.location = "http://yourdomain.com/updater.asp"`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: You can either send an Excel file *or* an HTML page, but not both.  You could save the excel file on the server and give the user a page with a link to the file, and an "update database" button.

Comment: I changed the confirmation to an alert('test'); just to make sure all other things were not affecting, but still does not work

Comment: Of course it doesn't - an HTTP response can't be both an excel file and an HTML page...